# bootstrap-table columns issue

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-table, bulma

I use the bootstrap-table to make my tables (NOT THE SAME AS BOOTSTRAP). I specifically use the Bulma version of bootstrap table. The url for this is http://bootstrap-table.com
. For some reason the tables I make with this has lines going down separating the columns, as can be seen in the image below. I tried everything removing this, any suggestions?

Below is my table html code.

```
<table data-checkbox="true" data-show-columns-toggle-all="true" data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="true" class="table is-narrow table-hover table-responsive" data-toggle="table" data-search-highlight="true" data-advanced-search="true" data-show-columns="true" data-show-fullscreen="true" data-id-table="advancedTable" data-mobile-responsive="true" data-sticky-header="true" data-pagination="true" data-search="true">
```

[image]